# Remove a component onClick in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm displaying a `overlay` page when a certain `input` is clicked. Now I want to remove that `overlay` page when a user `clicks` somewhere in that `overlay`. How can I do that?

I'm displaying the overlay on click like this

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showComponent: false,
        };
        this.popup_ques = this.popup_ques.bind(this);

    }

    popup_ques() {
        this.setState({
            showComponent: true,
        });
    }

 render() {
        return (
            <div className="ff">
                <div className="middle_div">
                    <input className='post_data_input' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt" onClick={this.popup_ques}/>
                </div>

                {this.state.showComponent ? <QuestionOverlay/> : null}

            </div>
        );
    }
```

My `overlay` is in the component `QuestionOverlay`

```
class QuestionOverlay extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    closeOverLay = (e) => {
        alert("fse");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            //Here I have implemented my overlay
        )
    }

}

export default QuestionOverlay;
```

So how can I close/remove the overlay component when I click somewhere on my overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function from the Overlay's parent component (the component which displays the Overlay) that is called `onClick` in the Overlay. This function will update `this.state.showComponent` of the parent to `false` to hide the Overlay.

**Parent**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        showComponent: false,
    };
    this.popup_ques = this.popup_ques.bind(this);
    this.hide_overlay = this.hide_overlay.bind(this);

}

popup_ques() {
    this.setState({
        showComponent: true,
    });
}

hide_overlay() {
  this.setState({
    showComponent: false
  })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="ff">
            <div className="middle_div">
                <input className='post_data_input' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt" onClick={this.popup_ques}/>
            </div>

            {this.state.showComponent && <QuestionOverlay hideOverlay={this.hide_overlay} />}

        </div>
    );
}
```

**Overlay**

```
class QuestionOverlay extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  closeOverLay = (e) => {
    alert("fse");
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div onClick={this.props.hideOverlay}>
          // Overlay content
        </div>
    )
  }

}

export default QuestionOverlay;
```

Comment: I think it would be better to do binding `this.hideOverlay.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: @Brett DeWoody: Your approach is good but it does not work for me. I have inserted a alert just to see if the click event works. And it does. So the problem is not changing the state of the component to false.

Comment: Try `{this.state.showComponent && <QuestionOverlay hideOverlay={this.hide_overlay} />} as opposed to the ternary. 
`

Comment: yeah I got it to work. you were correct all along. I don't know what happened but it's working now